# Crystal Reports IN-Statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

How can I use this kind of condition in crystal report?

Inside `SUPPRESS` condition

`If {REP_AccountingCashFlow_Get;1.ReferenceIdentifier} IN (1, 5, 9, 10) THEN
TRUE Suppress TRUE`

My error when I check my condition is `The ) is missing`

Anyone know how to solve this? or proper way to use this kind of condition in `Crystal Reports`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [here](http://www.algorithminc.com/blog/bid/171207/Crystal-Reports-IN-and-NOT-IN-Record-Selection), `Crystal Reports` uses `brackets[]` instead of `parenthesis()`.

So it would likely be `...IN [1, 5, 9, 10]` instead.

And your statement should be:

```
{REP_AccountingCashFlow_Get;1.ReferenceIdentifier} IN [1, 5, 9, 10]
```

You don't need to put an `if condition` anymore since adding a formula for `Suppress` is already considered an `if statement` that when matches your criteria will suppress the object in your `Crystal Report`.

Comment: ohh it works. so instead using like `( )` the proper is `[ ]` Thanks.